# Realizar una actualización de datos en Java sobre una BD XML BaseX

Tags: java, base-de-datos, xml, netbeans

Lo que pretendo hacer es modificar datos de una base de datos XML realizada con BaseX a través de una consulta xq, todo ello integrado en Java.

No es una base de datos servidor/cliente, sino que está almacenada en una dirección del disco duro.

El código que tengo hecho hasta ahora es este.

```
package tarea6_2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Open;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Set;
import org.basex.core.cmd.XQuery;

public class Tarea6_2 {

    //Nombre de Bilioteca o BD (Library): ciclosaugustobriga
    private static final String bdNombre = "ciclosaugustobriga";
    //ruta del Grupo de bases de datos:
    private static String directorioGrupoRoot = "/home/alberto/BaseXData";

    private static String directorioScriptsRoot ="/media/alberto/DATA/Documentos/Grado Superior/Curso 2/Acceso a Datos/"
            + "Trimestre 2/Unidad 6/Tarea 6/Consultas xq/";

    private static String[] scriptNombre = { "Ej2apartadoA.xq",
  "Ej2apartadoB.xq", "Ej2apartadoC.xq"};

    private static String[] scriptNombre2 = { "Ej2apartadoAA.xq",
  "Ej2apartadoBB.xq", "Ej2apartadoCC.xq"};

    //contexto de la BD
       static Context context = new Context();


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{



           //fichero para recoger cada script XQuery de consulta
    File scriptFile;
    File scriptFile2;

//Abre la base de datos ya creada en el contexto de la BD
new Open(bdNombre, directorioGrupoRoot).execute(context); 

new Set("intparse", true).execute(context);

try{
    //Para cada script con consulta XQuery
      for (int i = 0; i < scriptNombre.length; ++i) {
        //recoge la ruta del fichero de script con consulta XQuery
        scriptFile = new File(directorioScriptsRoot + scriptNombre[i]);
        scriptFile2= new File(directorioScriptsRoot + scriptNombre2[i]);
        //mensaje indicando el script XQuery que se ejecutará
        System.out.println("Ejecutando '" + scriptFile + "'...");
        String query=cargaScript(scriptFile);
        String query2=cargaScript(scriptFile2);

        //imprime la expresión de consulta XQuery
        System.out.println("---\n" + query + "\n---");


        new XQuery(query).execute(context);

        query(query2);

        System.out.println("-------------------------");   
        }
}finally{
    //cerramos el contexto y por tanto la BD    
 context.close(); 
}

    }//fin del main


/**************************************************************************
 * Método que devuelve la consulta XQuery (almacenada en fichero file) en una cadena
 * @param file
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 */  
  private static String cargaScript(File file)
          throws IOException {
   //Obtiene el contenido del fichero
    InputStreamReader in =
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
    //cadena para construir la cadena resultante
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    //array de tamaño suficiente para alamcenar los caracteres del script
    char[] chars = new char[8192];
    int count;
    try {
      //mientras hay caracteres en el contenido del fichero
      //los añade a la cadena
      while ((count = in.read(chars, 0, chars.length)) != -1) {
        if (count > 0) {
          build.append(chars, 0, count);
        }
      }
    } finally {
      in.close();
    }
     return build.toString();
  }



 /**
   * This method evaluates a query by using the database command.
   * The results are automatically serialized and printed.
   * @param query query to be evaluated
   * @throws BaseXException if a database command fails
   */
  static void query(final String query) throws BaseXException {
    System.out.println(new XQuery(query).execute(context));
  } 


}//fin de la clase principal
```

Las consulta las hace, pero las actualizaciones de datos no.

Añado las consultas:

Consulta 1:

```
declare namespace xhtml='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
//ciclo[@id=1] update replace value of node ./horas with '10'
```

Consulta 2:

```
declare namespace xhtml='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
for $d in //ciclo/nombre
return rename node $d as 'nombreciclo'
```

Consulta 3:

```
declare namespace xhtml='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
delete //profesor[nombre='Antonio Bernal']/email
```

Comment: Por favor pública también el código XQuery con el que haces la actualización para tener una idea de lo que hacen

Comment: Ya están añadidos, gracias por el aviso.